# join two SQL rows in a single one

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have three tables in Postgresql, for a biological classification system.

```
table lang (languages)

id       name
 1  português
 2    english

-------------------------------

table taxon (biological groups)

 id      name
...
101  Mammalia

-------------------------------

table pop (popular names)

id  tax  lang        pop
...
94  101     1  mamíferos
95  101     2  mammals
```

I want to get

```
 id      name     namePT   nameEN
101  Mammalia  mamíferos  mammals
```

but my join is giving me

```
 id      name        pop
101  Mammalia  mamíferos
101  Mammalia    mammals

select t.id,name,pop from taxon t
left join pop p on p.tax = t.id
where t.id = 101
```

How can I get the desired result in a single row?

Comment: Depends - how many pops can an id have?

Comment: @kbball only one for each language.

Comment: how many languages?

Comment: @kbball I'll change the query as I add new languages. Right now suppose I only have these two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy to change query every time you add a new language then this query will do the trick:

```
select t.id,name,pe.pop as eng_pop, pp.pop as port_pop
from taxon t
left join pop pe on pe.tax = t.id and pe.lang = 1
left join pop pp on pp.tax = t.id and pp.lang = 2
where t.id = 101
```

Comment: This looks the simplest and more correct answer so far. I'll take more time to increase my data to be able to compare their efficiencies, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN p.lang = 1 THEN p.pop END) AS namePT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN p.lang = 2 THEN p.pop END) AS nameEN
FROM taxon t
LEFT JOIN pop p
ON p.tax = t.id
GROUP BY t.id, t.name;
```

Comment: This only gives me the lines where there's a popular name. But some doesn't.

Comment: @Rodrigo then you should change to `LEFT JOIN` as in my edited answer

Comment: It was not only a matter of changing to LEFT JOIN, but inverting taxon with pop. Now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got the results:

```
with base as (
  select t.id, t.name,
  case when lang = 1 then 'mamiferos' else null end as namePT,
  case when lang = 2 then 'mamals' else null end as nameEN
  from taxon t
  left join pop p on t.id = p.tax
  group by 1,2,3, p.lang
) 
select 
   distinct id, 
   name, 
   coalesce(namept,'mamiferos',null) as namept, 
   coalesce(nameen,'mamals',null) as nameen 
from base 
where id = 101 
group by id, name, namept, nameen;

 id  |   name   |  namept   | nameen 
-----+----------+-----------+--------
101 | Mammalia | mamiferos | mamals
(1 row)
```